# "The boss of a company" or "the boss in the company"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which one of the following sentences is correct?

> Kate is the boss **of** a company.
>
> Kate is the boss **in** a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would say that:

> Kate is the boss of a company.

Implies that Kate is right at the top and is ultimately in charge. This might be CEO or it might be that Kate runs her own small business. Either way, she doesn't have a boss herself.

> Kate is the boss in a company.

Sounds far less natural and a bit more open to interpretation. Are you saying that Kate is a manager within the company? Are you saying that she is in charge completely and is 'the big boss'? Or are you saying that even if she might not be 'the one in charge' she is the one who you should talk to in order to get things done?

> Joe is the boss of the company, but if you want something to get done,
>   you go to Bob. You could say that Bob is the real boss in Example
>   Corp, just don't let Joe hear you say it!

Comment: I agree, "boss in a company" sounds like she might be a manager but not the director

Answer (score 1):

We would normally say the boss **of** a company, especially when they are *the* only boss.

"Boss" is a widely used term, but it isn't a job description. It could be used in place of "manager", but that word really describes what someone does - they manage people, or budgets, or whatever. "Boss" just says they are in charge generally. A person's job role is far clearer if you state their actual position, for example, "*he is the CEO of a company*".

Within a large organisation, you can have many managers, and those working under them may call those individuals "boss" - but there still might be one *senior* boss, manager, CEO etc above them. In that situation, it may be understood if you said they were "*a* boss *in* the company".